# How to mask an image within a given div by CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mask

Basically, I am doing a project which looks like this:

when a mouse moves over an image, the image inside a div will be enlarged through an animation, but only the part of image inside the div should be displayed, and the outer part should be clipped. Is there any way to clip the image, according to the width and height of the div? In my case, it only enlarged when the mouse hovers over it, but it is not clipped.

```js
$('.thumbnail').on('mouseover',
  function() {
    $(this).find('.thumb_pic').addClass('hover_effect');
  }
);

$('.thumbnail').on('mouseout',
  function() {
    $(this).find('.thumb_pic').removeClass('hover_effect');
  }
);
```

```css
.thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.thumb_pic {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.hover_effect {
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}

.mask {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

.mask:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img class="thumb_pic" src="/thumb_img/thumb.png" />
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So it's basically a form of enlarger? Like a zoom?

Answer (score 5):

```
.thumbnail{
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

you don't need the mask div. but why do you use jquery and not css? use `.thumb_pic:hover` instead of `.hover_effect` and remove your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE:** This isn't an answer, only a suggestion to make your code a little more efficient

Instead of using JQuery `mouseover` and `mouseout` do it with css

**Instead of**

```
.hover_effect {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

**Try**

```
.thumbnail:hover .thumb_pic {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the property you're looking for is "overflow: hidden"